# What will I do if my laptop is still updating morning to afternoon?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

What will I do if my laptop is still updating? At first it was so fast and then when it reach 5, it stopped and the update is not moving. What will I do? I just click update and restart from my laptop (Windows 8).

Comment: Visit Microsoft and run their updates troubleshooter to see if this solves your problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700567

Comment: This can be a major problem. You may be fine, but I've had an OS become totally corrupted via this situation. So, to be safe, back up your files JUST in case! I'm sure it will be fine, but better safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this case is to cancel the running updates.  You will find an icon in your task bar for windows updates which will allow you to do this.

Once you have done this, backup your data and reboot your PC.  It is important that you do this as rebooting after a bodged update can corrupt a PC.

After this, you should be able to run the update trouble shooter as I believe Matthew Williams commented: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700567

Once this is done, try again.  If it still fails, try a windows restore and then attempt the update agin.  This should work.

Also, remember to install windows updates with your antivirus turned off as I have often seen an update fail because the AV has been getting in the way.